# How to grab text from multiple instances of xpath in an XML document JAVA

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

Id like to grab the text values from multiple instance of the same XPATH which occur in different parts of an XML document. Example:

```
<explanation>
<NodeExplanations>
    <IDAfterSkipProcessing>/Temporary/EIC/EarnedIncomeWorksheetPP/SpouseLongSESelfEmploymentTaxAmtNotBlank</IDAfterSkipProcessing>
    <NodeExplanation>
        <Title>Spouse's self-employment tax</Title>
        <Phrase>
            <Text>your spouse does not have self-employment tax</Text>
        </Phrase>
        <Question>
            <Text>Why doesn't my spouse have self-employment tax?</Text>
        </Question>
        <ExplanationText>
            <Text>We can't get any more details on </Text>
            <NodeName>
                <Text>your spouse does not have self-employment tax</Text>
            </NodeName>
            <Text> right now.</Text>
        </ExplanationText>
    </NodeExplanation>
<NodeExplanations>  
</explanation>
```

I'd like to parsed out:

```
1. "We can't get any more details on "
2. "your spouse does not have self-employment tax"
3. " right now."
```

How can I grab the text values from the XPATHs mentioned? I want to avoid using DOM

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397232/xml-soap-and-xpath-query-with-multiple-instance-of-node

Comment: //Text[text()='...' or ...]

Comment: `//ExplanationText//Text/text()` should work as well.